# How can I fix the project build path error? I can't import the java.lang.math for a Java 8/9 Calculator app

Tags: java, eclipse, math, import, calculator

I am developing a simple calculator application in Java 8/9 in Eclipse. I am working on the power operation (as in "to the power of" used in math). I want to use the `Math.power()` instead of a `for` loop. However, I am having trouble importing the java math package into the program. The internet says to add `import java.lang.math`. When I try to code it in, I receive a notice of "Cannot Perform Operation. This compilation unit is not on the build path of the Java Project". What am I overlooking and/or doing wrong? Please provide suggestions or feedback.

Please note: Yes this is an academic assignment. To make this clear, I am not asking for the coding of the power operation. This issue is specifically about the importing the math package.

power operation (power.java)

```
package org.eclipse.example.calc.internal.operations;

import org.eclipse.example.calc.BinaryOperation;
// import java.lang.math; produces error 

// Binary Power operation

public class Power extends AbstractOperation implements BinaryOperation {
     // code removed. not relevant to SOF question.    
}
```

Main (calculator.java)

```
package org.eclipse.example.calc.internal;

import org.eclipse.example.calc.BinaryOperation;
import org.eclipse.example.calc.Operation;
import org.eclipse.example.calc.Operations;
import org.eclipse.example.calc.UnaryOperation;
import org.eclipse.example.calc.internal.operations.Power;
import org.eclipse.example.calc.internal.operations.Equals;
import org.eclipse.example.calc.internal.operations.Minus;
import org.eclipse.example.calc.internal.operations.Plus;
import org.eclipse.example.calc.internal.operations.Divide;
import org.eclipse.example.calc.internal.operations.Square;



public class Calculator {

    private TextProvider textProvider;

    private String cmd;

    private boolean clearText;

    private float value;

    public static String NAME = "Simple Calculator";

    public Calculator(TextProvider textProvider) {
        this.textProvider = textProvider;
        setupDefaultOperations();
    }

    private void setupDefaultOperations() {
        new Power();
        new Equals();
        new Minus();
        new Plus();
        new Divide();
        new Square();
    }

....
```

BTW, I use camel Case normally, but the academic project name everything including file names in standard writing format.

EDIT: After reading a response, I realized I forget to mention this. I can't get any further than typing `import java.`, then the error pop-ups. Then I can't type the rest of the import statement

[Image of package hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41a0A.png)

Comment: Java is case sensitive, you need to import `java.lang.Math` with a capital `M`: it's the name of the class. Eclipse can automatically add the import if you press `<CTRL+Enter>` after typing `Math`.

Comment: Thank. I realized that I forget to mention in my post. I can't get past `import java.` when typing. The error pops up and restricts the typing.

Comment: The problem is that `org.eclipse.example.calc` is only a sub-folder of `egit-training-start` instead of a Java project. Does right-clicking `egit-training-start` and choosing _Configure > Configure and Detect Nested Projects..._ fix your problem?

Comment: Eclipse did detect that there were nested projects. I managed to get it running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is not configured correctly. You have no source dir at all. The `src` dir should be marked as source dir; right click it and tell eclipse about this, or, as it is a maven project, it's more likely a broken pom. Also, why are you using the `org.eclipse` package? If you work for SAP, it should be com.sap.

Comment: I went and right-clicked on the project. Unfortunately, the build path expands to "no action available". IF it matters, it is hosted via Git/BitBucket. It also has 2 sub-packages within the primary package. That is out of my knowledge. Still learning. As for `org.eclipse`, this is academic. The university decided to use it. For the assignment, it was our job to produce the additional classes and import the class files to execute in the main calculator file. I am not happy with that and a few other things.

Comment: _The university decided to use it_. Huh. Some incompetent nincompoops running the cirriculum then, that is quite a silly thing. git/bb does not matter, the fact that it is a maven project might.